# Laravel 5 Class 'HTML' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am attempting to use Laravel 5 but my `{{ HTML::style('style.css') }}` No longer works.

I have updated composer.json to include `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` under require. I have added '`Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'` to my providers array under app.php and I have added

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

as well. I then ran `composer update`I have restarted WAMP to make sure and it still does not work. I have also tried to use  `{!! HTML::style('style.css') !!}` which did not work either. What else do I need to do to get this back?

Comment: after edit the `composer.json` has you ran `composer update`?

Comment: @manix Yes. I forgot to add that, I'll edit the question to include that I have done this too

Comment: remove the file storage/framework/services.json in order to regenerate the providers and try again

Comment: @manix Unfortunately sill nothing.

Comment: please, verify that `vendor\illuminate\html` folder exists

Comment: Have you tried adding `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` to your providers in `config/app.php` ? Also try this code to see if it's working:
`{!! Form::select('gender') !!}`

Comment: Try using `laravelcollective\html` instead of `illuminate\html`.

Answer (score 26):

Anybody who are using laravel 5.* have to use `laravelcollective/html` because Package `illuminate/html` is abandoned, you should avoid using it.

your `composer.json` file should contain following code in require section(as i am using laravel 5.2 it will be mentioned as 5.2)

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

run `composer update`

and your `config/app.php` should contain following code in providers array

```
'providers' => [
                       Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

]
```

and aliases should contain

```
'aliases' => [

                'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
                'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
]
```

and please note that whatever aliase you mentioned should appear in your code as

```
{{HTML::linkAction('MemberController@show', 'view', array($value->id))}}
```

Answer (score 16):

'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'

should be

'Html'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'

Answer (score 10):

I think it's a case sensitive problem.

If you register it as `'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'` in app.php, you can't use it as html or Html ( then it will only work when you use HTML).

Answer (score 9):

```
{!! Html::style( asset('public/css/artist.css')) !!}
```

... worked for me, but this

```
{{ HTML::style( asset('css/artist.css')) }}
```

... did not worked. But it should work. No!

Laravel is confusing me more from day to day. I try to learn this ... Notwell :D

Comment: See there is case sensitivity in your both code you have must registered html class like 'Html' so first one works. It's all about how registered HTML class no meter how you call it or print it.

Answer (score 8):

1 follow 
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Run the following from the terminal:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Now if you want

{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}

or

{!! HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}

//2 way follow.

```
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}

    //change to 

    {{ Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

or

```
    'aliases' => [
            // ...
              'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
              'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
            // ...
          ],

    //change to 

    'aliases' => [
            // ...
              'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
              'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
            // ...
          ],
```

for more see this video tutorial.....
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yl6hkoaCS6g

Answer (score 7):

1. **Add to composer.json:** 
     a) "illuminate/html": "5.*"
     b)  Run Command:-   composer update
2. **Add to the app.php providers array:**
    a) 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
3. **Add to the app.php aliases array:**
   a) 'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
   b) 'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
4. Done

Comment: In 5.3 the package to use is `laravelcollective/html` and not `illuminate/html`

Answer (score 4):

In the Laravel 5 "illuminate/html": "5.*" is deprecated and replaced with new dependency "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's composer.json file to require "laravelcollective/html"

In your composer.json file update the following:

```
"require": {
   "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
 // ...
 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
 // ...
],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
 // ...
   'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
   'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
 // ...
],
```

You can also check it here for Laravel 5

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Answer (score 1):

If  you must not use HTML Facade, do this for simplicity:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('style.css') !!}">
```

Comment: Solved my issue so easily, I guess we should not rely only on many classes to do such a simple work. It is way more valuable like this because you don't necessarily know where your app is located (local, remote server). Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this documentation how to fix it**:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

For each version you change the version number to access the appropriate doc e.g

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.x/html

> x is the version

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to configure Laravel 5 with macros:

1. `composer require laravelcollective/html`
2. In `/config/app.php`, under `"providers"`: `App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider::class`
3. Create `MacroServiceProvider.php` under `/app/Providers`:

   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   ```
   public function boot()
   {
       foreach (glob(base_path("resources/macros/*.macro.php")) as $filename) {
           require_once($filename);
       }
   }

   public function register()
   {
       //
   }
   ```

   }
4. Add any macros in the folder `/resources/macros` in the format `*.macro.php`.  Note the needed `$this->toHtmlString` in order to escape the string:

   Html::macro("something", function() {
       return $this->toHtmlString("

   Hi there

   ");
   });
5. Use macros in templates, [as described here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/181/creating-html-macros).

Answer (score 0):

> run this cmd to laravel installed folder

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

> and use with public

```
{!! Html::style( asset('public/css/artist.css')) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ URL::asset('style.css') }}` instead of `{{ HTML::style('style.css') }}`

Answer (score -1):

the app.php entries should be:

```
'providers' => [

    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],

'aliases' => [

    // ...
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
],
```

Answer (score -1):

I did the same thing as you did: added laravelcollective in my composer, did composer update, added them in my providers and aliases but the code below did not work:

```
{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg') }}
```

However, I have this working for me

```
{{ Html::image('img/picture.jpg') }}
```

I think this is because this issue is case sensitive and that the class HTML vs class Html is being seen as entirely different from one another by this laravel version.

Comment: I also face this issue. On one page HTML works and on other page Html works.  It includes the same namespaces as first page.Why is that?

Answer (score -2):

```
'providers' => [
     Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    ]

    'aliases' => [
          'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
          'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    ]
```

Comment: How is this any better than BillFromReno's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38819082/369450) or Shital Jachak's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39079405/369450)?