# Laravel change image in blade file with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use javascript to change an image in my blade file 
but am getting the following error. As a side note I have enabled HTML forms in laravel, and I am able to display images without javascript.

```
Fatal error: Class 'HTML' not found (View:/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/pages/progress.blade.php)
```

Below is my javascript code

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
changeImageForSeniorLevel();

};

function changeImageForSeniorLevel() {
var level = '<?php echo $levelValue; ?>';

if (level == 3)
{
document.getElementById("image").src="{{ HTML::image('progress2/Icons/Calls_Icon.png', 'alt',array('width' => 150 )) }}";
}
}
</script>
```

Here is the code for the image I am trying to change, the code will display an image if I comment my javascript.

```
{{ HTML::image('progress2/Icons/Meetings_Icon.png', 'alt', array('id' => 'image', 'width' =>150)) }}
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847726/laravel-5-class-html-not-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML::image` is a Laravel class / method that is parsed in PHP (which is hosted on your server).  You cannot parse it using a browser / HTML.  The browser does not know what `HTML::image` means.  In your case, you just want to change the attributes of an image already drawn on your document.

You can use the following to achieve what you are looking for:

```
if(level == 3){
    var myImage = document.getElementById("image");
    myImage.src = 'progress2/Icons/Calls_Icon.png';
    myImage.alt = 'alt';
    myImage.style.width = '150px';
}
```