# Undefined namespace html (adding a css file to blade) laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble with importing a css style sheet located in public/css in a blade file located in resources/views/includes.

The code I used in the blade file is

```
{{ HTML::style('css/layout.css') }}
```

which didn't work. I also tried

```
{{ HTML::style('css/layout.css', array('media' => 'print')) }}
```

The error I get is Class 'HTML' not found

I followed the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847726/laravel-5-class-html-not-found/), so

1. I added "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.16" in composer.json
2. run composer update
3. added in config/app.php

   ```
   'providers' => [
   Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
   ]
   ```
4. and

   ```
   'aliases' => [

           'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
           'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
   ]
   ```

Now the error I get is

```
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

And I don't understand why, as I added it to app.php. Indeed, when I go to app.php and the line where I added Collective.., the "Html" is colored in red and when I hover over it it says

```
Undefined namespace Html
```

What should I do about it? All this laravel thing is getting confusing to me.

Apart from the fact that I don't know what to do with,

```
{{HTML::linkAction('MemberController@show', 'view', array($value->id))}}
```

i found nothing online regarding the arguments of "linkAction"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:Remove `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.16"` in composer.json and clean other config for this package in config/app.php.

2:Run `composer update`

3:Run `composer require laravelcollective/html`

4:Add `'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class',` in config/app.php (providers)

5:Add `'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,` and `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`  in config/app.php (aliases)

6:In controller try `use Html;`  and `use Form;`

If you get any other error please share composer.json and config/app.php.