# error Class "HTML" not found - Laravel 5.4

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting the following error:

> Class 'HTML' not found (View:
>   C:\WORK\Software\XamppOne\htdocs\APOSTXUI\ContractorsClubField\resources\views\includes_header.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\WORK\Software\XamppOne\htdocs\APOSTXUI\ContractorsClubField\resources\views\includes_header.blade.php)

I have seen answers for 51., 5.2 and 5.3 - but - I have not seen anything for 5.4.

**This is what I got when I did the update:**

```
PS C:\WORK\Software\XamppOne\htdocs\APOSTXUI\ContractorsClubField> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating laravelcollective/html (v5.4.8 => v5.4): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.
```

I did the following:

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.3.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.4"
},
```

then I ran **composer update**

**I put the following in app.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    */

    'name' => 'Laravel',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        // FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847726/laravel-5-class-html-not-found
        //trying to use HTML class (KDC)
         Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
         'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    ],
    'serviceProviders' => [
        'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider',
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facade::class,
        //FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847726/laravel-5-class-html-not-found
        //trying to access the HTML class
        'FORM' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    ],

];
```

**Here is the snippet of code that is being ran**

```
<li>
          <a href="{{ HTML::linkRoute('logout') }}">
          <i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out </a>
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

TIA

Comment: try adding '\' before HTML it might be because of namespace problem: \HTML::linkRoute('logout')

Comment: @Paudel Views aren't namespaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravelcollectivehtml-in-laravel-53?page=1

```
$ php artisan config:cache
$ php artisan config:clear
```

The suggestion that this was due to an installation issue was wrong.
I also changed

"laravelcollective/html": "5.4"
to
"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no more `illuminate/html` for laravel 5.* (5.0 to 5.5 up) so in order to use code like {!!Html::style('css/font-awesome.min.css')!!} you must use `laravelcollective/html`

- In your composer file `composer.json` which is in th root folder of your project, in the require section add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"` depending of the version of your laravel so if you are using laravel 5.4 it should be `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"` your require section shoud look like `"require": {
      "php": ">=5.6.4",
      "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
      "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
      "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"
  },`
- update your laravel using `composer update` in your command prompt
- then on the file `config/app.php`
  add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` in the provider array
  and `'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
              'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,` in aliases array
  it should look like `'providers' => [

  ```
  /*
   * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
   */
  Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
  Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
  // what I just add
  Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

  /*
   * Package Service Providers...
   */
  Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

  /*
   * Application Service Providers...
   */
  App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
  App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
  // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
  App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
  App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
  ```

  ],`

`    'aliases' => [

```
    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    //what I just add
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],`
```

Everything should work Perfectly now...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful as well, the alias you are instructed to include in your config/app.php is 'Html', entering 'HTML' will not work, you can either change the alias to 'HTML' or start using it as Html::

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you try this it worked fine for me in laravel 7

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```