# Class 'Html' not found error with updated composer laravel 5.5.21 version.

Tags: php, laravel-5, href

I could not find a resource to correct my error. In my view with the following snippet:

```
Html::link('http://test.com')
```

I get the `Class 'Html' not found` error. My laravel version is 5.5.21.

Comment: kind of duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395822/error-class-html-not-found-laravel-5-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error Class "HTML" not found - Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395822/error-class-html-not-found-laravel-5-4)

Comment: it is the answer for 5.4 not 5.5.21

Answer (score 3):

Anybody who are using laravel 5.* have to use `laravelcollective/html` because Package `illuminate/html` is abandoned, you should avoid using it.

your `composer.json` file should contain following code in require section(as i am using laravel 5.2 it will be mentioned as 5.2)

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

run `composer update`

`config/app.php` should contain following code in providers array:

```
'providers' => [
                       Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

]
```

and aliases should contain:

```
'aliases' => [

                'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
                'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
]
```

Comment: it is work now. after did this it should have to run  config cache to clear cache.