# "Class 'HTML' not found" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.6 for my project. The problem is I got an error message `"Class 'HTML' not found"` when I include this tag in my form.

```
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}
```

I already included the `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"` in my composer, `config/app.php` and my controller.

Comment: Check this [Laravel 5 Class 'HTML' not found
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847726/laravel-5-class-html-not-found)

Comment: And [this link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html)

Comment: Hi Mohammad. As per the guidelines in _Meta_, please refrain from adding thanks or "please advice" (which is, in any case, misspelled). Readers know you need help, and any please-help-me material may be regarded as a form of begging. I've [asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52202600).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define Alias in app.php

```
 'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
// ...],
```

And use Html not HTML